# No virtual method findViewHolderForPosition(I) when trying to click on RecyclerView item with Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-proguard

I'm trying to make a simple espresso test that will find the first item in 
`RecyclerView` without specific label and click on it. To achieve this I added `espresso-contrib` to project like this:

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2') {
    // Necessary to avoid version conflicts
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

and wrote the following expression in my test case: 
`onView(withId(R.id.sresults_list_recycler)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnHolderItem(new FirstNotSoldOutMatcher(), click()).atPosition(1));`

Matcher works perfectly and `RecyclerView` got scrolled to the target item. But then I get error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method findViewHolderForPosition(I)Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView$ViewHolder; in class Landroid/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView' appears in /data/app/com.example-1/base.apk)
at android.support.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ActionOnItemAtPositionViewAction.perform(RecyclerViewActions.java:288)
at android.support.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ActionOnItemViewAction.perform(RecyclerViewActions.java:232)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:144)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

This looks strange to me. I read in Google documentation that `findViewHolderForPosition` method is deprecated now but it should still be there. I also have multidex enabled in the app but according to docs it is supported out of the box so shouldn't be a problem too.

Do you have any idea what can be wrong with this test?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, in my case problem was in `ProGuard` shrinking unused methods. Disabling it for tests helped.

For future seekers - if you don't want to disable proguard for debug build adding this line to proguard config should help too:

```
-keepclasseswithmembers public class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { *; }
```

Also, note that this rule should be added to the regular proguard file(the one of listed in `proguardFiles`) and not the test one(declared as `testProguardFile`)

Comment: @Bersh why in `proguardFiles` and not in `testProguardFiles`? they should be just for tests...

Comment: @Caipivara as I remember `testProguardFiles` were only applicable for tests code(in test apk) while we need to keep methods in the app itself

Comment: The weird thing is that I only get those crashes running my tests, when I use it manually it works fine without those rules

Comment: It's because then you use it manually in app/src, proguard sees it as dependency on that method and don't remove it, while if you use it in tests, proguard doesn't treat it as dependent code and removes the method

Comment: For androidx lib: 
-keepclasseswithmembers public class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView { *; }

Answer (score 3):

You can combine @Bersh's answer and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6084932) to be more strict about what to keep:

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView  {
    public android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder findViewHolderForPosition(int);
}
```

There is no reason to keep the entire `RecyclerView` class.

#### Update:

Or for when you inevitably update to AndroidX:

```
-keep class androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView  {
    public androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder findViewHolderForPosition(int);
}
```